# apt repository not showing in apt-cache policy, why?

Tags: apt, repository

I have a private mini-dinstall based repository. `sources.list.d` has an entry for it, like

```
https://user:pass@my.host/repos/ tools/
```

I have installed `apt-transport-https` and I can happily install packages in aptitude. That's good.

But `apt-cache policy` does not list it. And I wonder why and how to debug this?

Update: This is on debian/stable, and as requested, here is the output for a package in the private repos:

```
# apt-cache policy elrond-tools
elrond-tools:
  Installed: 1.0
  Candidate: 1.0
  Version table:
     1.0 0
        500 https://my.host/repos/ tools/ Packages
 *** 1.0 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**Update 2**: Okay, my confusion is increased now.
I have switched the URI to `http://10.*/` and suddenly it shows up. Then turned it back to the original `https` URL. And now that one works too.

Luckily my old stuff was still in the scrollback, and double checking it did not reveal anything new (as in: I have not missed something in the first place).

So I am confused now.

Comment: That's odd. For the individual packages in your private repos, what does `apt-cache policy pkgname` show, if anything?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Updated the question to include `apt-cache policy somepkg`.

Comment: What happens if you move it into  your main sources.list? Actually, what you have listed cannot be the complete line; there is not `deb` or `deb-src`. Can you post the actual sources.list.d entry for your private repos?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Doesn't look like it is making a difference. Currently I am even unable to reproduce this. (see second update). This IS confusing me.

Comment: It is odd that it is no longer reproducible. Did you you always remember to run `apt-get update` when adding stuff to sources? In any case you could go in to where apt stores its cache, remove the relevant files, and try again with https. Might be some https-specific bug, though it seems unlikely.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - Yes, I did run `apt-get update` (in fact `aptitude` then `u`), otherwise the `apt-cache policy pkgname` would not have shown the package on its repository (I even cut'n'pasted the complete backlog from the terminal to have logs of this for myself). Will try the cache removal tomorrow.

Comment: "Luckily my old stuff was still in scrollback" - have a look at [terminator](https://github.com/software-jessies-org/jessies/wiki/Terminator).